# register lengthMenu dataTables in session?

Tags: jquery, datatables

I use the [DataTables plugin](https://datatables.net/). I want to save `lengthMenu` in the session and if the user reopens the page we display the array with the same `lengthMenu` as saved in the session.

If he chose `50` we keep `50` in a session variable and if the user reopens the page we display it with the array with `50` elements. Here is the source code:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#Example').DataTable({
    "lengthMenu": [
      [10, 25, 50, -1],
      [10, 25, 50, "All"]
    ]
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DataTables already has this functionality built in. You can enable it by setting the `stateSave` property to `true`. Note that this technically uses a cookie, not the server side session, however the functionality is the same. Try this:

```
$('#Example').dataTable({
  stateSave: true,
  lengthMenu: [
    [10, 25, 50, -1],
    [10, 25, 50, "All"]
  ]
});
```

You can read more about `stateSave` and it's associated settings in the DataTables [documentation](https://datatables.net/reference/option/stateSave)

If you still required this to be saved in the session on the server, then you could use the [`stateSaveCallback`](https://datatables.net/reference/option/stateSaveCallback) and [`stateLoadCallback`](https://datatables.net/reference/option/stateLoadCallback) properties to make AJAX requests to get/set the session value.

Comment: No problem, glad to help